# A missing, sunset picture

Tags: knowledge, visual, video-games

[image]

In this picture, there is one missing picture (the question mark) that represents a word/phrase. What is that word/phrase?

> HINT 1: Each picture represents a word, which is part of a "list" that the question mark list completes. (Note each picture may have completely different context to each other.)

**EDIT: It has been pointed out to me that I have made a mistake in making the puzzle, please see the accepted answer for more detail.**

Comment: Just a quick question, apologies if this is the wrong place to put this, but what are the guidelines for further hints?

Comment: There is no regulation around hints, you're free to release them when you please. It is common practice, however, to spoiler them using ">!" in front of the hint. Some people release theirs after certain amounts of time or after the post passes a threshold of total views.
Also, welcome to PSE!

Comment: We usually wait for 24 hours before (and between) hints, that way people in all the different time zones get a chance to see the question.

Comment: It seems the game is Runscape

Comment: https://eso.mmo-fashion.com/leviathan/ here is the creature

Comment: @Moti rot13(lbh ner ba gur evtug genpx!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is something to do with:

> the online multiplayer first-person shooter, [*Destiny 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_2) - specifically, we are looking for something that represents one of the 'Raids' known as **Eater of Worlds** and **Spire of Stars**.

The three images depicted here represent the words:

> *Top-centre:* **Scourge** (this is the crest of [The Scourge](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Scourge) faction in World of Warcraft);
>  *Bottom-centre:* **Crown** (this is the [Royal Crown](https://oldschoolrunescape.fandom.com/wiki/Royal_crown) from Runescape);
>  *Right:* **Leviathan** (from the [Elder Scrolls](https://eso.mmo-fashion.com/leviathan/)).

The use of the word 'sunset' in the title suggests:

> a connection to 'sunsetting', i.e. the process of retiring or discontinuing a service.

Putting all of this together...

> In November 2020, when the *Destiny 2: Beyond Light* expansion was released, they [retired](https://www.polygon.com/2020/8/21/21395879/destiny-2-beyond-light-content-vault-leaving-retiring-sunset-raids-strikes-planets) (i.e. 'sunset') several of the [Raids](https://www.destinypedia.com/Raid) that could be played in the game. This list included the Raids known as **Leviathan**, **Scourge of the Past** and **Crown of Sorrow** - each represented in the puzzle image.
>
>  To complete the image we are looking for a fourth Raid that was discontinued at the same time - however, as far as I can tell (not being a *Destiny* player myself), there were *two* further Raid Lairs connected to the main Leviathan Raid that were also retired at this point: **Eater of Worlds** and **Spire of Stars**, so I would propose that the missing image represents one of these (though I cannot be 100% sure which would have been intended by the OP).
>
>  Tell you what, let's go safe and add an image which represents *both* **World** and **Stars** to cover all bases!
>
>  [image: World and Stars]
>  *<sup>Image source: [Cardiff University website](https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/research/explore/research-topics/physical-sciences-and-engineering/our-world-and-the-universe)</sup>*

Comment: Really good job, I thought this question might be here for a while, but someone answered it. As to your final box, that is my fault, as I never ran Eater of Worlds and forgot it existed, but brilliant answer!

Comment: @Capercailie Aha, that makes sense - thanks for clarifying. I'd suspected I was in the right ballpark but wasn't 100% sure :)